# Is big-O notation relevant for concurrent world?

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, time-complexity

In most popular languages like C/C++/C#/Erlang/Java we have threads/processes; there is GPGPU computation market growing. If algorithm requires N data independent steps we get not the same performance as if algorithm would require all steps follow one another. So I wonder if  big-O notation makes sense in concurrent world? And if it does not what is relevant to analyze algorithm performance?

You can have N or more processors in distributed environment (GPGPU / cluster / FPGA of future where you can get as many cores as you need - concurrent world, not limited to the number of parallel cores)

Comment: Yes, of course it does. Why wouldn't it?

Comment: Even with concurrency, you would at best be scaling your O(N) work by the number of processors available.  Scaled O(N) is still O(N).

Comment: You mean [big-O notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation)? O(N) generally means "linear time", not generic syntax encompassing all big-O notation. If not, I'm not really following your question.

Comment: @pjs: Only if the number of processors is fixed.  If you have an effectively unlimited number of processors, then things like bubble sort suddenly become linear time.  See [Sorting Networks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_network)

Comment: Please explain down vote.

Comment: @MooingDuck  Big-O is about how the work scales, not about the amount of time it takes to do a particular sized job. I use cluster computing on a regular basis, and even though I have access to thousands of processors the number is not unlimited.  With the tasks I work on I can always saturate the number of processors available, and thus have to worry about scalability.

Comment: @pjs: Sure.  That's because you don't have an effectively unlimited number of processors.  If you have unlimited processors, then the work _depth_ scales in a different manner.  Work _size_ scales the same though.

Comment: @MooingDuck That's the whole point, nobody does.  I work with large scale design of experiments.  If you can point me to where I could run 2**100 parallel processes, I'd be thrilled - I regularly deal in design spaces that are even larger than that.

Comment: @pjs: Are you saying that big-O notation is only for real world examples that you've experienced and has nothing to do with theory at all?  Because Knuth would disagree with you.  I also observe that there is no actual turing machine either.  Please read the wikipedia summary on sorting networks.

Comment: @MooingDuck Not at all what I'm saying.  I'm saying that my real-world experience shows that I have real-world problems that make the big-O notation relevant even in the presence of "effectively unlimited number of processors", because 2**100 is more than the estimated number of subatomic particles in the universe. Even if every subatomic particle could be harnessed for computation, I'd need more than that to directly tackle the class of problems I deal with.

Comment: @pjs: Big O notations (and modern complexity theory and theoretical computer science) often make assumptions of infinity, because the majority of them are based on a turing machine with infinite storage space that can store an infinite number of symbols on each "cell".  Given this, working with the concept of an infinite number of them is not exactly a big deal.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/53983/discussion-between-mooing-duck-and-pjs).

Comment: I am amused that all four close votes currently in place for this question have different reasons: Off topic (Programmers), Unclear, Too Board, and Opinion Based.

Comment: FYI, we have made some theoretical progress on this. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NC_(complexity)

Answer (score 6):

Big-O notation is still relevant.

You have a constant number of processors (by assumption), thus only a constant number of things can happen concurrently, thus you can only speed up an algorithm by a constant factor, and big-O ignores constant factors.

So whether you look at the total number of steps, or only consider the number of steps taken by the processor processing the most steps, we end up with exactly the same time complexity, and this still ends up giving us a decent idea of the rate of growth of the time taken in relation to the input size.

> ... future where you can get as much cores as you need - concurrent world, not limited to the number of parallel cores.

If we even get to the stage where you can run an algorithm with exponential running time on very large input in seconds, then yes, big-O notation, and the study of algorithms, will probably become much less relevant.

But considering, for example, that for an `O(n!)` algorithm, with `n = 1000` (which is pretty small to be honest), it will require in the region of `4x10^2567` steps, which is about `4x10^2480` times more than the mere [`10^87` estimated **number of atoms in the entire observable universe**](http://www.universetoday.com/36302/atoms-in-the-universe/). In short, big-O notation is unlikely to ever become irrelevant.

---

Even on the assumption of an effectively unlimited number of processors, we can still use big-O notation to indicate the steps taken by the processor processing the most steps (which should indicate the running time).

We could also use it to indicate the number of processors used, if we'd like.

The bottom line is that big-O notation is to show the rate of growth of a function - a function which could represent just about **anything**. Just because we typically use it to indicate the number of arithmetic computations, steps, comparisons or similar doesn't mean those are the only things we can use it for.

Comment: Saying you have N! processes/threads does not mean exactly having N! cores for each one of them. So they can be emulated while more RAM/frequency than you have you can not get. My main intrest was if there is any Big O notation alternative that would respect and take in abilety of algorithms to make use of parallel.

Comment: @DuckQueen I added a bit to my answer - hopefully that helps. Big-O notation is sufficient to indicate the running time of a concurrent process and, as such, there isn't a need for something else (at least that's what I assume most people in CS academia believe, which is why there isn't a (well-known) alternative). "Well-known" because, well, we can't know everything everyone ever came up with.

Answer (score 0):

Big-O is a mathematical concept. It's always relevant, it would have been relevant before computers even existed, it's relevant now, it will always be relevant, it's even relevant to hypothetical aliens millions of light years away (if they know about it). Big-O is not just something we use to talk about how running time scales, it has a mathematical definition and it's about functions.

But there are many [models of computation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_of_computation) (unfortunately many people forget that, and even forget that what they're using is a model at all) and which ones make sense to use is not always the same.

For example, if you're talking about the properties of a parallel algorithm, assuming you have a constant number of processing elements essentially ignores the parallel nature of the algorithm. So in order to be able to express more, a commonly used model (but by no means the only one) is [PRAM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_random_access_machine).

That you don't actually have an unlimited number of processing elements in reality is of no import. It's a model. The whole point is to abstract reality away. You don't have unlimited memory either, which is one of the assumptions of a Turing machine.

For models even further removed from reality, see [hypercomputation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercomputation).

Answer (score 0):

Multithreading and using gpu's just uses parallelization to speed up the algorithms. But there are algorithms that cannot be speeded up this way.

Even if algorithms can speeded up by parallelization, a `O(N log N)` algorithm will be much faster than a `O(N²)` algorithm.